# How to use parameter in Ireport 4.5 when using xpath and xml as Datasource

Tags: xpath, parameters, jasper-reports, ireport

Does anyone know how to use a parameter within and xpath in Ireport. I am using 4.5

I have something like this that works:

```
<fieldDescription><![CDATA[origin/localizedNames/name[@lang = "en"]]]></fieldDescription>
```

and what i want to do is something like

```
<fieldDescription><![CDATA[origin/localizedNames/name[@lang = "$P{lang}"]]]></fieldDescription>
```

Where lang is my parameter... but it does not seem to work and i cant find any example on the net.

thanks in advance,
Dimitri

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`parameters`** in *`XPath`* expressions.

The sample:

```xml
<queryString language="xPath"><![CDATA[/Northwind/Orders[CustomerID='$P{CustomerID}']]]></queryString>
```

You can find the sample in folder ***`%jasperreports%\demo\samples\xmldatasource`*** from [JasperReports distribution package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%204.5.0/).

You can also read [this article](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xmldatasource/index.html#xpathqueryexecuter) about *`XPath`* using.

Comment: <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/station/name[@lang = '$P{lang}']]]></fieldDescription> does not seems to work?